# Is there a way to set kptr_restrict to 0?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

I am currently having trouble running linux perf, mostly because `/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict` is currently set to 1.

However, if I try to `/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict` by echoing 0 to it as follows...

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

I get a permission denied error. I don't think I can change permissions on it either.

Is there a way to set this directly somehow? I am super user. I don't think perf will function acceptably without this being set.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your example, `echo` is running as root, but your shell is running as you.

So please try this command:

```
sudo sh -c " echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict"
```

Comment: Or `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict`

Answer (score 27):

All the files located in `/proc/sys` can only be modified by `root` (actually 99.9% files, check with `ls -l`). Therefore you have to use `sudo` to modify those files (or your preferred way to execute commands as root).

The proper way to modify the files in `/proc/sys` is to use the `sysctl` tool. Note that yu should replace the slashes (`/`) with dots (`.`) and omit the `/proc/sys/` prefix... read the fine manual.

Read the current value:

```
$ sysctl kernel.kptr_restrict 
kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
```

Modify the value:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w kernel.kptr_restrict=0
sysctl kernel.kptr_restrict=1
```

To make your modifications reboot persistent, you should edit  `/etc/sysctl.conf` or create a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/50-mytest.conf` (edit the file as root or using `sudoedit`), containing:

```
kernel.kptr_restrict=1
```

In which case you should execute this command to reload your configuration:

```
$ sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

P.S. it is possible to directly write in the virtual file. https://stackoverflow.com/users/321730/cdyson37 command is quite elegant: `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict`