# perf: Couldn't record kernel reference relocation symbol

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

I have compiled `perf` for my kernel (3.11.10). During the compilation, some libraries were missing, so I have installed those.

But now when I run `perf`, I get following message:

```
Couldn't record kernel reference relocation symbol
Symbol resolution may be skewed if relocation was used (e.g. kexec).
Check /proc/kallsyms permission or run as root.

Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) were restricted.
Check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict before running 'perf record'
If some relocation was applied (e.g. kexec) symbols may be misresolved.
Samples in kernel modules can't be resolved as well.
```

Since  I am using custom build kernel, the most obvious explanation to me is, that some option is missing from my kernel. If so, how can I find out what is missing?

**I am not sure what exactly `perf` is complaining about. How can I fix this?**

**EDIT:**

`/proc/kallsyms` does not exist and `/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict` contains `0`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
0
```

I have compiled the kernel myself, and it is possible that it is missing some option. What is this `/proc/kallsyms` ? How can I enable it in my kernel?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What is your kernel? Is it from the linux distributive you use or is it compiled by you (how did you install it)?

First part of warning says about  /proc/kallsyms - can you show output of the command (started from the same user you used to run perf)

```
ls -l  /proc/kallsyms
cat /proc/kallsyms | head
```

Second part of the `perf` message says about kptr_restrict sysctl setting. Can you do

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

to check the setting. Basically, to profile the kernel symbols you should either disable kptr_restrict by setting it to zero (as described in https://lwn.net/Articles/420403/ or https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Profiling):

```
# Run as root user - e.g. after doing "sudo bash"
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

or (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20391360/196561)

```
sudo sh -c " echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict"
```

or

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

or you can always run the `perf` from root user.

After setting kptr_restrict to zero or when running perf from root you should get no warning about kallsyms and will be able to profile kernel functions.

Update: seems that `perf record` always want access to kallsyms/restricted kptrs, even with userspace-only event (`-e cycles:u`)

Answer (score 8):

This tutorial worked perfectly for me!

http://lost-and-found-narihiro.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-install-perf-kernel-performance.html

Copied from the tutorial:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
1
$ echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
0
```

Answer (score 2):

@osgx and @Kelly have already given the solution.

In order to make the change to `kptr_restrict` permanent, one could do the following:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "kernel.kptr_restrict=0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'
sudo sysctl -p
```

Note: The above worked on my machine, the `sysctl` configuration file could be located elsewhere in other machines. For e.g., `/etc/sysctl.d`.

Inspired by [this tutorial](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-01/use-perf/).